# Android Failed to find this app in the PackageManager io.crash.air

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using Android studio and the Fabric plugin.
I've already been able to report a crash to Fabric.

My app's Gradle build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {

    }
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also getting same error.. did you get any solution?

Comment: @Pallavi not yet, I will post an answer myself once I find a solution

Comment: This issue is not Fabric related. There's something in your app which makes the exception. I had the same problem.

Comment: @Alireza something fixed by upgrading crashlytics that can be accessed and configured through Fabric 

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This issue solved in 2.6.1 version. Upgrade your crashlytics version from 2.6.0 to 2.6.1

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer for the time, till Fabric sort it out.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - is this causing an error or a warning?

Comment: Thanks for confirming, we just shipped a fix for this - will add a new answer.

Comment: 2.6.1 only removes the logging: according to the release notes _Removed logging when the Beta by Crashlytics app cannot be found_ . Release 2.6.2 may have fixed the core problem but it's unclear: _Updated Crashlytics Core dependency_. At least it doesn't show the message like 2.6.0 does.

Answer (score 9):

Mike from Fabric here.

Sorry for this error! Version 2.6.1 of Crashlytics corrects this. Release notes here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#id6

Answer (score 8):

Clean, rebuild did not work for me, I went back to 2.5.7, so for the time being my app build.gradle now is back to (and no more exception) :

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```